# Rails ActionMailer with multiple SMTP servers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smtp, actionmailer

I have a need to use two different smtp servers in a Rails application. It appears that the way ActionMailer is constructed, it is not possible to have different smtp_settings for 
a subclass. I could reload the smtp settings for each mailer class whenever a message is being sent, but that messes up the ExceptionNotifier plugin which is outside my control (unless I mess with it too). Does anyone have a solution/plugin for something like 
this?

Ideally I would like to have

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base; end
```

and then set in environment.rb

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = standard_smtp_settings
UserMailer.smtp_settings = user_smtp_settings
```

Thus, most of my mailers including ExceptionNotifier would pickup the default settings, but the UserMailer would use a paid relay service.

Comment: For more reference, here is a pull request which was finally only merged onto Rails 4, as Rails 3.2 was not accepting new features.

https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/7397

Comment: See @wnm's answer for the Rails 4 way, with a link to the docs.  It's quite simple now. http://stackoverflow.com/a/34948143/456791

Answer (score 25):

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def welcome_email(user, company)
    @user = user
    @url  = user_url(@user)
    delivery_options = { user_name: company.smtp_user,
                         password: company.smtp_password,
                         address: company.smtp_host }
    mail(to: @user.email,
         subject: "Please see the Terms and Conditions attached",
         delivery_method_options: delivery_options)
  end
end
```

Rails 4 allows for dynamic delivery options. The above code is straight from the action mailer basics guide, which you can find here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.0/action_mailer_basics.html#sending-emails-with-dynamic-delivery-options

With this, it is possible to have different smtp settings for every email you send, or, like in your use case for different sub classes like UserMailer, OtherMailer etc.

Comment: The best answer. Works perfectly in Rails 4 :D

Comment: Seems like using a callback is also an accepted option... https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-callbacks: "Using an after_action callback also enables you to override delivery method settings by updating mail.delivery_method.settings."  May also be cleaner in a real-world scenario given your delivery settings are most likely a function of the environment they are being used in

Answer (score 20):

Based on the Oreilly article, I came up with the solution I wrote about here:
http://transfs.com/devblog/2009/12/03/custom-smtp-settings-for-a-specific-actionmailer-subclass

Here's the relevant code:

```
class MailerWithCustomSmtp < ActionMailer::Base
  SMTP_SETTINGS = {
    :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port => 587,
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name => "custom_account@transfs.com",
    :password => 'password',
  }

  def awesome_email(bidder, options={})
     with_custom_smtp_settings do
        subject       'Awesome Email D00D!'
        recipients    'someone@test.com'
        from          'custom_reply_to@transfs.com'
        body          'Hope this works...'
     end
  end

  # Override the deliver! method so that we can reset our custom smtp server settings
  def deliver!(mail = @mail)
    out = super
    reset_smtp_settings if @_temp_smtp_settings
    out
  end

  private

  def with_custom_smtp_settings(&block)
    @_temp_smtp_settings = @@smtp_settings
    @@smtp_settings = SMTP_SETTINGS
    yield
  end

  def reset_smtp_settings
    @@smtp_settings = @_temp_smtp_settings
    @_temp_smtp_settings = nil
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - this looks like a good solution (thought I don't have enough reputation to vote it up). I ended up switching from ExceptionNotifier to HopToad which made the O'Reilly solution again posible.

Comment: I had to add :domain => 'localhost:3000', :authentication => :plain, :enable_starttls_auto => true, to get it to work but this is the best solution I have found

Comment: and of course change localhost:3000 to the appropriate domain in production

Comment: But this seems to suffer from the concurrency problems described in @jcalvert's answer to [How to send emails with multiple, dynamic smtp using Actionmailer/Ruby on Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662759/how-to-send-emails-with-multiple-dynamic-smtp-using-actionmailer-ruby-on-rails).

Answer (score 20):

Solution for Rails 4.2+:

***config/secrets.yml*:**

```
production:
  gmail_smtp:
    :authentication: "plain"
    :address: "smtp.gmail.com"
    :port: 587
    :domain: "zzz.com"
    :user_name: "zzz@zzz.com"
    :password: "zzz"
    :enable_starttls_auto: true
  mandrill_smtp:
    :authentication: "plain"
    :address: "smtp.mandrillapp.com"
    :port: 587
    :domain: "zzz.com"
    :user_name: "zzz@zzz.com"
    :password: "zzz"
    :enable_starttls_auto: true
  mailgun_smtp:
    :authentication: "plain"
    :address: "smtp.mailgun.org"
    :port: 587
    :domain: "zzz.com"
    :user_name: "zzz@zzz.com"
    :password: "zzz"
    :enable_starttls_auto: true
```

***config/environments/production.rb*:**

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = Rails.application.secrets.gmail_smtp
```

***app/mailers/application_mailer.rb*:**

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: '"ZZZ" <zzz@zzz.com>'

  private

  def gmail_delivery
    mail.delivery_method.settings = Rails.application.secrets.gmail_smtp
  end

  def mandrill_delivery
    mail.delivery_method.settings = Rails.application.secrets.mandrill_smtp
  end

  def mailgun_delivery
    mail.delivery_method.settings = Rails.application.secrets.mailgun_smtp
  end
end
```

***app/mailers/user_mailer.rb*:**

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  # after_action :gmail_delivery, only: [:notify_user]
  after_action :mandrill_delivery, only: [:newsletter]
  after_action :mailgun_delivery, only: [:newsletter2]

  def newsletter(user_id); '...' end # this will be sent through mandrill smtp
  def newsletter2(user_id); '...' end # this will be sent through mailgun smtp
  def notify_user(user_id); '...' end # this will be sent through gmail smtp
end
```

Answer (score 10):

For anybody approaching this issue with later versions (3+) of Rails, try this

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#sending-emails-with-dynamic-delivery-options

Comment: This is the cleanest solution!

Answer (score 6):

Tried to use jkrall's option with Rails 3.2.1 but for some reason it wouldn't override default configuration, but doing:

```
MyMailer.my_email.delivery_method.settings.merge!(SMTP_SETTINGS).deliver
```

Similar to http://www.scottw.com/multiple-smtp-servers-with-action-mailer, made it work.

Comment: fyi - merge! returns a hash which doesn't have a deliver method.

Comment: The blog post mentioned has had its URL changed and can now be found at http://dev.scottw.com/multiple-smtp-servers-with-action-mailer.

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/a/6413630/242426. There's also a pull request that was merged into Rails 4+ to add support for this out of the box - https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/7397

Answer (score 2):

Rails-2.3.*

```
# app/models/user_mailer.rb
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def self.smtp_settings
    USER_MAILER_SMTP_SETTINGS
  end

  def spam(user)
    recipients user.mail
    from 'spam@example.com'
    subject 'Enlarge whatever!'
    body :user => user
    content_type 'text/html'
  end
end

# config/environment.rb
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = standard_smtp_settings
USER_MAILER_SMTP_SETTINGS = user_smtp_settings

# From console or whatever...
UserMailer.deliver_spam(user)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it's not doable natively.
But you can trick it a bit by modifying the @@smtp_settings variable in the model.

There's an article on Oreilly which explains it pretty well even though they code is not clean at all.
http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2009/03/using-multiple-smtp-accounts-w.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I saw that article, and that is what I meant by reload the smtp settings before each mail (which is what the article did in the load_settings method). This is close to a solution, but it messes up ExceptionNotifier because I cannot reload the settings for it without changing the plugin. I was hoping there for something more maintainable.

Comment: Unfortunately, because of the way it is implemented, it's not possible.

Comment: Anything's possible with enough monkey patches.

Comment: Please help get this PR merged in rails. (https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/7397). This does exactly what  the OP is thinking of easily.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/AnthonyCaliendo/action_mailer_callbacks

I found this plugin helped solve the problem for me pretty easily (as in < 5 mins).  I simply change the @@smtp_settings for a particular mailer in the before_deliver and then change it back to the defaults in the after_deliver.  Using this approach, I only have to add the callbacks to mailers that need @@smtp_settings different than the default.

```
class CustomMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  before_deliver do |mail|
    self.smtp_settings = custom_settings
  end

  after_deliver do |mail|
    self.smtp_settings = default_settings
  end

  def some_message
    subject "blah"
    recipients "blah@blah.com"
    from "ruby.ninja@ninjaness.com"
    body "You can haz Ninja rb skillz!"
    attachment some_doc
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution, which, while it looks ridiculous, I think is a little bit cleaner and easier to reuse in different AM::Base classes:

```
    module FTTUtilities
      module ActionMailer
        module ClassMethods
          def smtp_settings
            dict = YAML.load_file(RAILS_ROOT + "/config/custom_mailers.yml")[self.name.underscore]
            @custom_smtp_settings ||= HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(dict)
          end
        end

        module InstanceMethods
          def smtp_settings
            self.class.smtp_settings
          end
        end
      end
    end
```

example Mailer:

```
    class CustomMailer < ActionMailer::Base
        extend FTTUtilites::ActionMailer::ClassMethods
        include FTTUtilites::ActionMailer::InstanceMethods
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Rails 3.2:

```
class SomeMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  include AbstractController::Callbacks
  after_filter :set_delivery_options

  private
  def set_delivery_options
    settings = {
      :address => 'smtp.server',
      :port => 587,
      :domain => 'your_domain',
      :user_name => 'smtp_username',
      :password => 'smtp_password',
      :authentication => 'PLAIN' # or something
    }

    message.delivery_method.settings.merge!(settings)
  end
end
```

Solution inspired by [How to send emails with multiple, dynamic smtp using Actionmailer/Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662759/how-to-send-emails-with-multiple-dynamic-smtp-using-actionmailer-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 0):

When I wanted a quick test in the console (Rails 5) I did the following:

```
settings = { username: "" } # etc
mailer = MyMailer.some_method
mailer.delivery_method.settings.merge!(settings)
mailer.deliver
```