# Rails mail parameters from user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

Instead of setting mail smtp parameters in environment specific initializers; I would like the end-user specify it from administration page.

How to achieve it?

Comment: What is the motive behind this change, explain the functionality in brief

Comment: Our app serves to many different types of companies, users, etc. Each user should set his/her own mail parameters, so the app will send notifications from the users company email address.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662759/how-to-send-emails-with-multiple-dynamic-smtp-using-actionmailer-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 0):

you can set any kind of ActionMailler config/settings dynamically, just by changing it (which imo is a bad approach. if you offer a saas then youre also capable of sending emails)

```
def my_controller_action
  ActionMailer::Base.server = "mail.gmail.com"
  ActionMailer::Base.username = "huan-son"
  #...
end
```

From the Railsdoc

> smtp_settings - Allows detailed configuration for :smtp delivery
>   method:
>
> :address - Allows you to use a remote mail server. Just change it from
>   its default “localhost” setting.
>
> :port - On the off chance that your mail server doesn't run on port
>   25, you can change it.
>
> :domain - If you need to specify a HELO domain, you can do it here.
>
> :user_name - If your mail server requires authentication, set the
>   username in this setting.
>
> :password - If your mail server requires authentication, set the
>   password in this setting.
>
> :authentication - If your mail server requires authentication, you
>   need to specify the authentication type here. This is a symbol and one
>   of :plain (will send the password Base64 encoded), :login (will send
>   the password Base64 encoded) or :cram_md5 (combines a
>   Challenge/Response mechanism to exchange information and a
>   cryptographic Message Digest 5 algorithm to hash important
>   information)
>
> :enable_starttls_auto - Detects if STARTTLS is enabled in your SMTP
>   server and starts to use it. Defaults to true.
>
> :openssl_verify_mode - When using TLS, you can set how OpenSSL checks
>   the certificate. This is really useful if you need to validate a
>   self-signed and/or a wildcard certificate. You can use the name of an
>   OpenSSL verify constant ('none', 'peer', 'client_once',
>   'fail_if_no_peer_cert') or directly the constant
>   (OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE, OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER, …).
>
> sendmail_settings - Allows you to override options for the :sendmail
>   delivery method.
>
> :location - The location of the sendmail executable. Defaults to
>   /usr/sbin/sendmail.
>
> :arguments - The command line arguments. Defaults to -i -t with -f
>   sender@address added automatically before the message is sent.