# Allowing users to specify their own mail server settings. Rails 5.x with ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer

So I'm nearly complete with setting up a mailer in my Rails app, but I cannot seem to understand one of the pieces of information on https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html.

According to this tutorial, you can specify your own `smtp_settings` option, so that you can send mail like:

```
def welcome_email
    smtp_settings = {
        address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
        port:                 587,
        domain:               'example.com',
        user_name:            'myfromemail@example.com',
        password:             "myPassword",
        authentication:       :plain,
        enable_starttls_auto: true
    }

    mail(to: "destination@example.com",
        subject: "Test Notification",
        smtp_settings: smtp_settings
        )
end
```

but this doesn't actually work. The same example at the bottom uses `delivery_method` and passes over a hash just like I used in this example.

If I try to use the `.deliver` method on the mailer, this is the error I get:

> Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost"
>   port 25)

It's almost like it's completely ignoring the smtp settings that I passed to the `mail` function. What am I doing wrong here?

I've looked at examples from [How to send emails with multiple, dynamic smtp using Actionmailer/Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662759/how-to-send-emails-with-multiple-dynamic-smtp-using-actionmailer-ruby-on-rails), but this method does not work:

`delivery_method.settings.merge!(smtp_settings)`

because the `delivery_method` is actually `:smtp` and it's not possible.

The `delivery_method` option seems to work, but I need to pass additional stuff over like authentication, SSL/TLS, and even the port. Those don't seem to be offered by the `delivery_method` option.

Trying to implement one of the solutions on that post gives me this error:

```
MyMailer.delivery_method.settings.merge!(smtp_settings)
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):3
NoMethodError (undefined method `settings' for :smtp:Symbol)
```

Comment: Did you take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6413630/4160532) answer?

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna that's the exact answer I'm referencing. Going to update my answer to clarify.

Comment: btw, how are you going to get those setting, are you going to store them in DB ?

Comment: Can you try this ? `instance_email = Mailer.welcome_email`
`config_settings = {address: 'xyz.com', port: 587}`
`instance_email.delivery_method.settings.merge! config_settings`
`instance_email.deliver`.

Comment: Ahh!! I was missing a step! Thank you VERY much. This does the trick! Thanks!!!!!!!

Comment: I'll be adding this as an answer, could you please accept it, if it helped.

Comment: Done :) Thanks gaain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Dynamic mail server settings, you need to configure in the following way

```
instance_email = Mailer.welcome_email
config_settings = {address: 'xyz.com', port: 587}
instance_email.delivery_method.settings.merge! 
config_settings instance_email.deliver
```